# How can I make an approximate number and close to reality based on N?

Tags: mysql, sql

Her is my tables:

```
// users
+----+--------+------------+----------------+------------+
| id |  name  | reputation |     avatar     | visibility |
+----+--------+------------+----------------+------------+
| 1  | John   | 344        | er0942334r4... | 1          |
| 2  | Peter  | 65544      | 340ojfc343f... | 0          |
+----+--------+------------+----------------+------------+

// posts
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
| id | title  |  content   | author_id |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
| 1  | title1 | content1   | 2         |
| 2  | title2 | content2   | 1         |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT p.*,
       COALESCE(u.name,'NoName') as `name`,
       u.reputation as `rep`,
       COALESCE(u.avatar,'default') as avatar
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN users u
ON u.id = p.author_id AND u.visibility = 1
```

And here is the **current** output:

```
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
| id | title  |  content   | author_id |  name  | rep  |     avatar     |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
| 1  | title1 | content1   | 2         | NoName |      | default        |
| 2  | title2 | content2   | 1         | John   | 344  | er0942334r4... |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
```

As you see, `rep` column will be empty where `user.visibility = 1`. Now I want to create an approximate number and close to reality from the real value of `users.reputation` and set it there.

So here is the **expected** result:

```
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
| id | title  |  content   | author_id |  name  | rep  |     avatar     |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
| 1  | title1 | content1   | 2         | NoName | +5k  | default        |
| 2  | title2 | content2   | 1         | John   | 344  | er0942334r4... |
+----+--------+------------+-----------+--------+------+----------------+
```

Here is all possible cases as `rep`:

- `1`
- `+100`
- `+1k`
- `+5k`
- `+20k`
- `+100k`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to re-structure the query a bit, moving the logic for "visibility" into the `SELECT`.

I'm not sure what the exact logic is for `rep`, but here is an example:

```
SELECT p.*,
       (CASE WHEN u.visibility = 1 THEN u.name ELSE 'NoName' END) as `name`,
       (CASE WHEN u.visibility = 1 THEN CAST(u.reputation as VARCHAR)
             WHEN rep < 100 THEN '1'
             WHEN rep < 1000 THEN '+100'
             . . .
        END) as `rep`,
       (CASE WHEN u.visibility = 1 THEN u.avatar ELSE 'default' END) as avatar
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.id = p.author_id;
```

This assumes that `rep` is stored as a number in the table.  The values that you are outputting need to be strings, however.

Comment: Your solution works perfectly ... But there is a vague thing for me: The speed of my query is much faster, why? I created a benchmark and for 1000 times execution, **mine: 2.4sec**, **yours: 4.7sec**. Why?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . This version needs to process all the rows in `users`.  If most have the visibility flag set to `0`, then that will filter out a lot of data.  I'm a bit surprised the difference in performance would be that (relatively) large, but it might make a difference.